# Setting the default browser with gulp-open and yargs

Tags: gulp

I am setting up the default browser using [`npm install yargs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) and using [`gulp-open`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-open) to automatically open the browser on the default `gulp` task

```
// $:> gulp
gulp.task('default', ['express', 'watch'], function () {

  // Create browser option argument / Default on chrome
  var selectedBrowser = args.browser ? args.browser : 'chrome';
  // Open browser
  var open = require('gulp-open')
  gulp.src('src/index.html')
  .pipe(open({
      app: selectedBrowser,
      uri:"http://localhost:" + config.server.port
  }));

   gutil.beep();
})
```

This works fine but i would like the default option which is currently chrome to be the users default browser. If i run `.pipe(open())` without any configuration the my default browser opens ( it is currently edge ) which is the functionality that i would like. I am just not sure what property to add for the default. On the npm page for gulp-open there only seems to opens for firefox and chrome, not even to sure what the name is for edge. I have tried `microsoft-edge` ,`edge`,`microsoftedge` and `default`

---

*I would like to set the default property to the default browser*

`var selectedBrowser = args.browser ? args.browser : 'chrome';`

*replacing the current `'chrome'` argument*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that takes any guess work out of it:

```
gulp.task('default', ['express', 'watch'], function () {
  var params = {
    uri:"http://localhost:" + config.server.port
  };
  args.browser && params['app'] = 'chrome'; 
  var open = require('gulp-open');
  gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(open(params));

  gutil.beep();
})
```

I created a named object and pass it to the open function. It creates the 'app' key/value only if args contains a truthy value for browser.

Comment: interesting solution! I used ending up using `iexplore`, forgot that i opened this question.